# IMAP ENABLE OR DISABLE FOR GMAIL

Tags: gmail

I use android tablet along with my apple phone, and desk computer, do I enable or disable Imap to read my emails across all devices

Answer (score 0):

You want IMAP enabled.

If you do this then when you read a message on your phone, it won't show up as unread on your other devices.

If you answer a message, your answer is stored  on the IMAP server, and appears in the Outbox on all your devices.

Note that GMAIL's use of labels is not fully compliant with IMAP.  A gmail label corresponds to an IMAP folder.  But a given message can have multiple labels.  To do this in IMAP you have to have multiple copies of your message, and threading goes to hell.

IMAP clients will treat labels as folders, so if a messages has 3 labels put on it, it will be downloaded 3 times into 3 separate folders.